# Backbone fetch not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, marionette

Following Backbone/Marionette Controller and Collection won't fetch.

```
define(["jquery", "backbone","models/Poi"],
    function($, Backbone, Poi) {
        // Creates a new Backbone Poi class object
        var PoiCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model:Poi,

            parse: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                // Return people object which is the array from response
                return response;
            }
        });

        // Returns the Poi class
        return PoiCollection;
    }
);
define(['App', 'backbone', 'marionette', 'views/MapView', 'views/DesktopHeaderView', 'views/DesktopFooterView', 'models/Poi'],
        function (App, Backbone, Marionette, MapView, DesktopHeaderView, DesktopFooterView, Poi) {
            return Backbone.Marionette.Controller.extend({
                initialize: function (options) {
                    App.headerRegion.show(new DesktopHeaderView());
                    App.mainRegion.show(new MapView());
                    App.footerRegion.show(new DesktopFooterView());
                },
                //gets mapped to in AppRouter's appRoutes
                index: function () {

                    console.log("Ajax::list of POI");
                    var p = new Poi();
                    p.fetch({
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log("data");
                        }
                    });
                    console.log(p);
                }
            });
        });
```

I have no Idea where to look to debug this. The Network tab tells me that the data was fetched, but the success method is never called.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `fetch` call itself looks OK, but two other apparent bugs could be affecting that call:

1) Your log message in the `index` function says "**list** of Poi", but you're using a (single) `Poi` instance -- should that be `PoiCollection` instead? I'm assuming the `Poi` model (not shown above) is for a single item.

2) There's no `url` property in the `PoiCollection`, so if you did `fetch` a `PoiCollection` instead, that call would fail because `PoiCollection` doesn't know what URL to use. The most common pattern with Collection + related Model is to put an `url` only in the Collection, and no `url` in the single Model for the Collection's individual items (`Poi` in this case). Backbone will construct the corresponding individual-model URLs as needed based on the parent Collection's `url`. I think getting the `url` straightened out will help here.

Finally, one more thing: the fist parameter passed to the `fetch` call's `success` function is the Model or Collection instance itself, not the raw data object. That's not relevant for the current `success` code you have now (you're only logging a static string), but it will be relevant as soon as you try using that parameter. :-)